# How to add video in carousel bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have a gallery on my website. I'm new at bootstrap world so I'm wondering if you guys can help me. At the bottom is my source code, when I clicked the image it will just show a big preview of the picture so I'm trying to do is make it a video with controls. I hope you understand and can help me. BTW I'm editing a template website so I really don't know how to fix this one.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div id="gallerySLide" class="gallery_area">
                <a href="videos/1.mp4" title="This is Title">
                    <img class="gallery_img" src="img/gallery/img-small1.jpg" alt="img" />
                <span class="view_btn">View</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Images : https://ibb.co/mtZNLk
https://ibb.co/mns3RQ

Comment: video tag? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can embed a video by using the video element in HTML 5, the controls attribute will display the controls of the video.

```
<div id="gallerySLide" class="gallery_area">
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: I want it inside the carousel, sir. https://ibb.co/mns3RQ As you can see I'd like the big picture to be replace by a video if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `video` tag and if there is unsupported browser, message will be displayed

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div id="gallerySLide" class="gallery_area">
                <video title="This is Title" poster="img/gallery/img-small1.jpg" controls>
                    <source src="videos/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want it inside the carousel, sir. https://ibb.co/mns3RQ As you can see I'd like the big picture to be replace by a video if possible. Thank you.

Comment: https://ibb.co/cMBuGQ what I really mean sir is when i click the small picture the video will be played in the carousel. I'm sorry if I'm not clear at explaining things, I just really need this one.

Comment: @Mmezreal You can add `poster` property to the tag